# Upgrade Mongodb data

Tags: mongodb

I'm moving my database from 1 cluster (replica set of 3 nodes) to a new one and wanted to profit to upgrade my database version. I'm using 3.6 now and want to upgrade to the latest (4.4).
I'm allowed to shutdown the service for a couple of hours.

According to what I found as information, here is how I'm planning to do:

- Shutdown the current service
- Copy the data folder of the primary node to the new server
- Install 4.0 binaries
- Start the database and run `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.0" } )`
- Install 4.2 binaries
- Start the database and run `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.2" } )`
- Install 4.4 binaries
- Start the database and run `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.4" } )`
- Install 4.4 binaries to the other 2 nodes and add them to the cluster.
- Restart the cluster

Does that look correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "cluster"? Do you run a Replica Set?

Comment: Yes I have a replica set of 3 nodes

Comment: Upgrade secondary members of the replica set.
Step down the replica set primary and upgrade that node.
Enable backwards-incompatible 4.4 features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend to combine these two actions. Do it separately.

Would be like this:

**Upgrade to Mongo 4.4**

- Shut down the SECONDARY member
- Replace the binaries
- Restart the SECONDARY member
- Step down the replica set PRIMARY member
- Replace the binaries on stepped-down PRIMARY
- Run `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.0" } )`
- Repeat above till you reached version 4.4

Have a look at [Post Upgrade tasks](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2-upgrade-replica-set/) for each release. Setting FeatureCompatibilityVersion may also take some time.

**Move to new server**

- Install MongoDB on new host
- Add new hosts to Replica Set: `rs.add( { host: "new_host_1.example.net:27017" } )`

  Inital sync takes place and may take some time. I would recommend to add new hosts one-by-one
- Step down the replica set PRIMARY member (on old host), ensure new primary run on a new host.
- Stop Mongo service on old hosts
- Remove old hosts from Replica Set: `rs.remove("old_host_1.example.net")`

Instead of adding 3 new nodes and then removing 3 old nodes, you can do it of course one-by-one, i.e.

- add one new node to Replica Set
- remove one old node from Replica Set
- repeat above three times

Just ensure when you run `rs.add/rs.remove` that all members are either in `PRIMARY` or `SECONDARY` state!

By this your application has no downtime at all.